# $A=\frac{9a^2}{a^2+1} + \frac{16b^2}{b^2+1} + \frac{25c^2}{c^2-2}$

Tags: inequality

Let: $a,b,c \geq 0$. Find the minimum value of:$$A=\frac{9a^2}{a^2+1} + \frac{16b^2}{b^2+1} + \frac{25c^2}{c^2-2}$$

I try to find the the minimum of it by try to put number into each variable.

For: $(x;y;z)= (0,4;0,2;0,4)$ will have $Min_A=\frac{-2750}{8671}\approx -0,3171491177$

For $(x;y;z)=(0,5;0,25;0,5)$ will have $Min_A=\frac{-494}{595} \approx-0,83$

Is there any solution? When $Min_A= \frac{-494}{595}$ $\Rightarrow c^2 -2 <0$ So it will be unable to use inequality with condition $\geq 0$.

Can anyone help me? Thanks a lots!!!

Comment: Do you mean $a,b.c\geq 0?$

Comment: There is no minimum. You can make $c$ so that $c^2-2$ is negative and arbitrarily close to $0,$ and hence the value can be made arbitrarily negative.

Comment: Let $\epsilon >0$. For $ A(a=0, b=0, c=\sqrt{2-\epsilon} ) = -25(2-\epsilon)/\epsilon \to -\infty$ as $\epsilon \to 0$. So, for $a,b,c \geq 0$, $inf(A) = -\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

i assume you mean a,b,c ≥0
if so think of A as a function of those 3 variables so A=A(a,b,c)
if you are familiar with Multivariable Calculus then the problem becomes ''easy'' as in you need to find where the partials are 0 for each variable
if not then my argument would be as follows
clearly we need to have all variables between 0 and 1-is there any number you can think of such that any of the denominators does not get smaller?(so basically does there exist the smallest a? or b? or c?)
if yes then plug that number in and do the same for the other 2 denominators and see what you get
if not then what do you think the answer is?